# How to set up browsers in VM's for testing purposes

Tags: cross-browser, virtualization

## You Need Various Browsers

So, you need to test
your web stuff
with various browsers.

Some of these browsers
may be unavailable
on the OS
in which you develop.

Microsoft browsers (Internet Explorer)
are only available for Windows.
Further,
each Windows installation
can have only a single
Microsoft browser.

Also, Safari is only available in OS X.

## The Obvious Solution: Virtualization

The obvious solution is
[hardware virtualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_virtualization).
The idea is to host
[virtual machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine)
in your development system,
in which you'll be free to install
the [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system)
and browser combination
that you require for testing.

## So, How?

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

## `ievms`

An easy and popular way
for developers to
get some VM's with
Microsoft browsers
up and running
is [`ievms`](http://xdissent.github.io/ievms/).

### Time and Storage Saving Tip Regarding `ievms`

To save time and storage,
intall only those browsers that you intend to use.

Answer (score 0):

## Safari: Only on OS X

The latest version of
[Safari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_(web_browser))
is available only for
recent versions
of [OS X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X).

running of OS X in virtualization
is supported only on
Apple hardware.

For further details, read:

- [VirtualBox's documentation on OS X guests](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-macosxguests)
- [VMware's "Virtualizing Apple Mac OS X (1000131)"](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1000131).

Answer (score 0):

## Manually

You can
create VM's
and install
the OS/browser
combinations
that you require.

I recommend [VirtualBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox).

### Advantages of Manual

You do not have to
discard
the changes in the VM
after each use session.

And, unlike with ievms,
you do not have to
reinstall from scratch
every time the license expires.

Apart from saving time,
this means that
you can configure/customize
the operating system and browser
and install additional software
according to your requirements and preferences.

### The Disadvantage

Valid licenses for the
software involved
may be required by law.

### Tips

- The same version of browser
  may behave differently
  on different versions of Windows.
- Provide enough memory to your VM's.
  I recommend at least 1GB, per VM.
  To be sure,
  check how much memory is free
  during a typical testing session.
- If you wish to test on
  multiple versions
  of Internet Explorer,
  see you install from
  Windows installation media
  that includes the version of Internet Explorer
  that you require
  and not a newer one.
- Virtualization software
  (like [VirtualBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox))
  have powerful snapshot features.
  Take snapshots after you make configuration
  changes or install software or updates.
  In case something goes bad,
  you would be able to easily revert.
- Clone the VM instead of
  installing the same version of Windows
  on multiple VM's.
  After you install Windows on one VM,
  clone it into a linked clone
  (this is VirtualBox terminology)
  and then simply upgrade Internet Explorer.
  Choose to reinitialize the MAC addresses when you clone
  (VirtualBox asks about this).
- Make sure that the
  browser will remain the same version
  by turning off automatic updates
  or choosing to ignore
  the specific browser updates.
- Disable System Restore.
- Disable the screensaver.
- Install the VirtualBox Guest Additions
  and upgrade them each time you upgrade VirtualBox.
- Configure your web browser
  (home page, new tab page,
  automatic form filling,
  disable "accelerators", etc.).